# Office.context.mailbox.item.categories.addAsync gives error: The operation is not supported

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to use Office.context.mailbox.item.categories.addAsync which was made available in requirement set 1.8. I can now install the add-in using the 1.8 MinVersion, but I receive this error when calling the method:

> error: OSF.DDA.Error
>
> name: "Host Error"
>
> message: "The operation is not supported."
>
> code: 5000

Related: [isSetSupported('Mailbox', '1.8') returns false in add-in running in OWA with Office365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58756762/issetsupportedmailbox-1-8-returns-false-in-add-in-running-in-owa-with-off/58761389#58761389)

Is there any idea when this will be supported in the Outlook Web client?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

API Requirement 1.8 is now supported on OWA, and you should be able to call categories.addAsync. If you're unable to add a category, can you please execute:

```
    Office.context.mailbox.masterCategories.getAsync
    (
        function (asyncResult)
        {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(asyncResult.value));
        }
    );
```

And see if that works? You should ideally be seeing a list of master categories.

Also, categories.addAsync currently works only in Mail Read Mode for OWA. Are you trying to use this from the Mail Compose mode?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use this in Mail compose mode. Using your code snippet, I do get back all of the categories. I am trying to set the category on a mail item using:     Office.context.mailbox.item.categories.addAsync. Referenced here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.categories?view=outlook-js-1.8#addasync-categories--options--callback-   Will this method be supported in Mail Compose mode in the future? Thank you for your help! Much appreciated!!

Comment: Since OWA doesn't support it natively on compose mode, the API isn't exposed for it. It will be supported once native feature is available to add categories in mail compose mode. Unfortunately we do not have an ETA as of now.

Comment: Can you tell me if this is supported yet?